# How long it takes to apply "Website restrictions" on the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

It has been over 2 hrs from the time I removed the Website restrictions, but the change is not taking any effects. Anyone knows how long it takes?

The API was working fine until I added the  "Website restrictions", by mistake I added the domain without the * at the end eg: https://example.com/* , so now the API stopped responding. I try to remove the "Website restrictions" but the outcome has not changed. So I was checking if anyone know how long it takes for the "Website restrictions" to take effect?

Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error
Your site URL to be authorized: https://example.com/something

Answer (score 0):

On my case was closed to 4 hrs to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

It should only take up to **~5-10 minutes** for new API key restrictions to take effect. Please do make sure that you are using the correct API key in your site.

If you are still encountering this issue, kindly file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel for the technical support to further investigate.